# How can I set permissions for a users group to see only one page?

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to set permissions for a users group to see only one page?
Can it be done via Site settings or is this a programmable task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on 2007 version, 2010 might be slightly different, but the idea is the same.

1. Create your group of users in People and Groups, but don't assign
   them permissions in Advanced permissions.
2. Navigate to the library that holds your page.
3. Go into the Library, find the page in question, mouse over it to
   reveal the drop down list and select Manage Permissions.
4. Click Actions, Edit Permissions clicking OK to the popup.
5. Add your previously created group with read permissions.

Users will have direct access to the page and will need the exact URL to get there.  They won't be able to hit the top level of the site/collection and navigate to it.

Comment: I've done as you said. The problem is that  you can still view all site content by enter the url /_layouts/viewlsts.aspx. Can we prevent this?

Comment: They can still see that but they won't be able to drill into them as Ernst noted.

Comment: And if I want to restrict that? So I give user a link, he can only see this page but not even the list of libraries? Because it's rather confidential stuff. Is it possible?

Comment: Create a new master page with the View All site content scoped to a different permission set like ManagePermisions or something like that and apply that to the site.  Then view all site content won't be visible. Or wrap the whole left nav in an elevated permission role.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to PirateEric:
Because you give read permissions to the group/user, they will get limited access to the rest of the site. They cannot navigate to the top (because they have no permissions on that page), but they will see the left navigation with all the links to document libraries and lists... (They cannot see the contents.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Delegate feature to redirect to the Access Denied page, when they are accessing viewlsts.aspx or settings.aspx.
https://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/create-an-additionalpagehead-control-packed-into-a-feature-in-visual-studio-2010/

We have created this deleagte control using additionalpagehead, which restricts user for the list of pages(XML). you have to use delegate control, as you cannot write code in system masterpage.

Thanks,
Nilesh 
http://nileshmandekar.blogspot.com